# Rails Undefined Method Path for New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am relatively new to rails but having a real problem with something that I know should be really simple. I have a model called channel, in it I have a simple new method, in the view I have form but every time I try and load it, I get an error to say:

```
undefined method `channels_path'
```

My view (new.html.erb) is really simple, for the minute it just has a button in it with a name and a value, it just looks like this:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @channel do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Free Plan', name: 'plan', value: 'free' %>
  <% end %>
```

My Controller has:

```
  def new
    @channel = Channel.new
  end
```

And in my routes I have:

```
resources :channel
```

Output form a rake routes is:

```
channel_index GET      /channel(.:format)                     channel#index
                         POST     /channel(.:format)                     channel#create
             new_channel GET      /channel/new(.:format)                 channel#new
            edit_channel GET      /channel/:id/edit(.:format)            channel#edit
                 channel GET      /channel/:id(.:format)                 channel#show
                         PATCH    /channel/:id(.:format)                 channel#update
                         PUT      /channel/:id(.:format)                 channel#update
                         DELETE   /channel/:id(.:format)                 channel#destroy
```

Which all looks how I expect. But as the error says there is no channels_path, but as far as I am aware, there shouldn't be.

I am sure this is supposed to be really simple but I just cannot see what I am doing wrong. Can anybody help?

Many thanks
David

**EDIT**

I have updated the route to be:

```
resources :channels
```

I can now load the form, however I now get the error when trying to submit it:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: channel
```

Being caused by:

```
  # only allow specific params
  def channel_params
    params.require(:channel).permit(:name,
                                    :slug,
                                    :description,
                                    :plan,
                                    :subscription_ends
    )
  end
```

I am assuming singular is correct here based on the model, but have tried plural too with no luck. Any more thoughts?

Many thanks

**Edit**

Got it working in the end, it appears you have to have at least one input in your form. I added an input for the name field and it started working.

Many thanks to everyone that commented

Comment: Yes singular `:channel` should be correct for the strong parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your rake task, the path should be

`channel_path`

If it's not working with the simple_form_for helper, it's probably because you should have set up your routes as `resources: channels`

UPDATE

The new bug is coming from nothing being received by the controller for :channel

Try adding a field like so

```
f.hidden_field :plan, :value => "free"
```

Comment: Yea, I am confused as to why it is pluralising it. Do I need to create this manually though. I would of thought the correct path should be a POST to /channel?

Comment: When you are creating a new record, you are posting it to the collection of the existing objects. This is why it's pluralized :)

Comment: The cow is correct.  You are declaring the resource incorrectly in routes.rb

Comment: Yeah I think the problem is that he defined `resources: channel` instead of `resources: channels` in routes.rb

Comment: Fantastic, thanks all!! So paths and channel are plural and model is singular? I have updated that to channels, renamed my controller and my views folder, and I can now load the form!! However when I post it, I get the same error as posted in my edit, any more thoughts?

Comment: Where is this line in your routes coming from? Is it still showing up when you run the rake task? `channel_index GET      /channel(.:format)                     channel#index`  I would expect  `channels GET      /channels(.:format)                     channels#index`.  I don't know if that's causing your error but it looks odd.

Comment: Try adding the name=free as a hidden field instead of on the button. It must be that the controller is receiving nothing for the channel. `f.hidden_field :plan, :value => "free"`. Also, the field name for 'plan' if entering it manually should be `channel[plan]`

Comment: I figured it out, it appears I have to have at least one field in there, I added a name field and it started working!! I will just modify how I was going to do it slightly, many thanks for your help all!!